# Alternating values within groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df1
    a   b                                  
4   0   1      
5   0   1      
6   0   2      
2   0   3          
3   1   2   
15  1   3   
12  1   3   
13  1   1     
15  3   1   
14  3   1   
8   3   1   
9   3   1   
10  3   2
```

I need another column that groups by a,b and assigning the values 1,2 alternating, always starting with 1, within each group of a.
It should look like this:

```
    a   b   c                               
4   0   1   1   
5   0   1   1   
6   0   2   2   
2   0   3   1       
3   1   2   1
15  1   3   2
12  1   3   2
13  1   1   1   
15  3   1   1
14  3   1   1
8   3   1   1
9   3   1   1
10  3   2   2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach could be to [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), take the [`ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) which basically enumerates each group, then take the `2` modulo and use the result to index from either `1` or `2`:

```
import numpy
df['c'] = np.array([1,2])[df.groupby(['a','b']).ngroup().values%2]
```

---

```
print(df)

    a  b  c
4   0  1  1
5   0  1  1
6   0  2  2
2   1  2  1
3   1  3  2
15  1  3  2
12  1  3  2
13  1  4  1
15  3  1  2
14  3  1  2
8   3  1  2
9   3  1  2
```

---

Update so that each  now group in `a` starts with `1` (adapting @wen's answer):

```
df['c'] = df.groupby('a').b.transform(lambda x : x.factorize()[0]%2+1)

print(df)

    a  b  c
4   0  1  1
5   0  1  1
6   0  2  2
2   0  3  1
3   1  2  1
15  1  3  2
12  1  3  2
13  1  1  1
15  3  1  1
14  3  1  1
8   3  1  1
9   3  1  1
10  3  2  2
```

Comment: Thank you. This is almost what I want. Within each group of 'a' it should always start with 1. If you look into the last 4 rows, it starts with 2. How can I fix that?

Comment: Right I see, Ill try to adapt @MirekG

Comment: This is what came to my head.

Comment: Works now @MirekG ?

Comment: this works perfectly, however slowly with a huge dataframe. Thank you so much!

Comment: Didn't know that. Just did it ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use `transform` + `factorize`

```
df.groupby('a').b.transform(lambda x : (x.factorize()[0]+1)//2+1)
4     1
5     1
6     2
2     1
3     2
15    2
12    2
13    2
15    1
14    1
8     1
9     1
Name: b, dtype: int64
```